# Unwanted hyperlink - how to remove?

Tags: php, inheritance, hyperlink

When the search box is used the title on the results page ("You have been mentioned in:") has an unwanted hyperlink, the same as one of the social media hyperlinks I manually inserted into the header.

The code for my header is:

```
<body <?php body_class() ?>>

    <div id="container">

        <div class="wrapper">

            <div id="header">

                <div id="logo"><h1>
                    <img src="/uploads/2013/08/LogoSpaced40.png" alt="Tell Him Her" />
</h1>
                </div><!-- / #logo -->

                <div id="menu" class="dropdown">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('container' => '', 'container_class' => '', 'menu_class' => 'dropdown', 'menu_id' => 'nav', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="cleaner">&nbsp;</div>

                <?php if ( function_exists( 'get_smooth_slider' ) ) { get_smooth_slider(); } ?>

                <div id="twitter_icon">
<a href="http://twitter.com/###" target="_blank" alt="Twitter"><img src="/uploads/2013/06/64x64-twitter.png" /></li></div>
              <div id="facebook_icon">
<a href="http://facebook.com/###" target="_blank" alt="Facebook"><img src="/uploads/2013/06/64x64-facebook.png" /></li></div>

         </div><!-- end #header -->

        </div><!-- end .wrapper -->
```

And the CSS for the social media links is:

```
#twitter_icon {
position: relative;
float: right;
margin-top: -155px;
margin-right: 12px;
}

#facebook_icon {
position: relative;
float: right;
margin-top: -75px;
margin-right: 12px;
}
```

The relevant search results code is:

```
$output = '<div class="searc-output-comments">';
        if(count($commenters) != 0) {
            $output .= '<div class="fixtitle1">You have been mentioned in:</div>';
        }else{
            $output .= '<div class="fixtitle1">You have not been mentioned. Maybe you should mention someone yourself...</div>';
        }
        $cc = 1;
        if ($paged > 1) $cc = ($count * $paged) - ($count -1);

        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++){

                    $comment = $commenters[$i];
                    $permalink = get_permalink( $comment['comment_post_ID'] );
                    $output .= '<div class="output-post">';
                    $output .= '    <div class="postcounter">'.$cc.'</div>';
                    $output .= '    <div class="s-p-wrap">';
                    $output .= '        <div class="s-p-w-top">';
                    $output .= '            <span class="author-name"><a href="'.$permalink.'#comment-'.$comment['comment_ID'].'">'.$comment['comment_author'].'</a></span>';
                    $output .= '            <div class="comment-date">'.time_ago($comment['comment_date']).'</div>';
                    $output .= '        </div>';
                    $output .= '    <div class="s-p-w-bottom">';                    
                    $output .= '            <p>'.$comment['comment_content'].'</a></p>';
                    $output .= '        </div>';
                    $output .= '    </div>';
                    $output .= '</div>';
                    $cc++;


        }
```

Basically the code:

```
$output .= '<div class="fixtitle1">You have been mentioned in:</div>';
            }else{
                $output .= '<div class="fixtitle1">You have not been mentioned. Maybe you should mention someone yourself...</div>'
```

Is displaying the hyperlink from the facebook social media link and can't figure out why.

Sorry if this is a long winded way of asking the question but didn't want to miss anything out. Anyone have any ideas?

If you need any further information or code please ask!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="twitter_icon">
<a href="http://twitter.com/###" target="_blank" alt="Twitter"><img src="/uploads/2013/06/64x64-twitter.png" /></li></div>
              <div id="facebook_icon">
<a href="http://facebook.com/###" target="_blank" alt="Facebook"><img src="/uploads/2013/06/64x64-facebook.png" /></li></div>
```

typo: opening an a tag and closing a li